# Blender attachment points for Trainz asset

Tags: modeling

It has taken me 12 months to learn basic blender, my first ever modelling experience, an engine shed for end user "Trainz TANE".
Basically model is near completion, and what I want is to attach an existing Trainz asset (a length of track) to my model, thus making a point for the end user to connect their incoming rail track to.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a mesh from Trainz you will need to figure out what format the game uses and if necessary convert it to a format that blender supports importing (OBJ or FBX are good ones). You may then need to set up textures again in Blender.

However attachment points are something specific to the game, and not something blender understands. To create attachment points you need to add an empty at the right location and prefix its name with "a." (e.g. a.attachment_1). It looks like the game will infer that it is an attachment point based on this convention.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trainz/Tutorial_for_Blender#Attachment_Points
http://online.ts2009.com/mediaWiki/index.php/Attachment_point
http://online.ts2009.com/mediaWiki/index.php/HowTo/Export_from_Blender_using_FBX